# jQuery Datepicker not closing after date selected

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a simple jquery Datepicker - but it isn't auto closing when a date is selected (or if the focus changes to another part of the page). Essentially it never closes...

Here's my code:

```
<input id="startDateField" class="dp" name="startDateField" type="text" size="8">

<script>
    $('input#startDateField').datepicker({autoclose: true});
</script>
```

Comment: Are there any errors on the debug console? Which datepicker library are you using? If jQuery UI, then `autoclose` is not a recognized option. In any case, this code works for me with _jQuery UI_ and _eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker_.

Comment: Works for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/fz00jxur/

Comment: Weird, my code doesn't work locally but works here: http://jsfiddle.net/bLbcez6t/

Comment: It can be browser issue, because you haven't specified a type in the script tags.

Comment: Adding this didn't help: <script type="text/javascript">

Answer (score 0):

Try This !

```
$('input#startDateField').datepicker({autoHide: true});
```